# Overlapped JLabel in Frame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am writing a code in Java Swing in which a label is added in frame on the click of the button. And the Labels are added such that it overlap each other to create a stack like view.

I am creating my own layout using label.setbouds(x,y,100,100) function.
And each time button is clicked in its action listener a new label is added.
For example

```
 if(e.getSource()==button){
                   label.setBounds(x+5,y+5,100,100);
                   frame.add(label);
                   frame.repaint();
              }
```

Now the problem is when these labels are painted the first label added always remain on the top and newly add Labels are overshadowed by odd label.

I need a help if someone could explain how i can paint the frame such that newly added frames comes on the top and old labels get overlapped.Any suggestion is appreciated

Regards

ACoder

Answer (score 5):

Insert your labels in a `JLayeredPane` with the proper index. Also make sure to set your `JLabel` as opaque (`setOpaque(true)`) so that it will actually obscure the content of the labels below. However, if a label below is bigger than the label on top, you will still see some part of it